Is it ok to just discard a certificate authority if there is only one valid certificate?
I have inherited a Windows Server 2019 domain controller on a small network (approx. 30 client pc's) with AD CS installed. I want to set up a dedicated server for AD CS since having the AD CS on the DC is bad practice and I'm planning to use certificates for Radius authentication for users/computers.
I have studied the process to transfer a ca to another computer but since all certificate templates are unconfigured and the key-length of the root certificate is only 2048 bits, I'd prefer to start all over.
Currently the only certificate still valid is a domain-controller certificate. The DC syncs with Entra, which I believe requires the domain-controller certificate.
Questions:

is it acceptable to drop the complete ca in this case?
will the DC just take a fresh domain-controller certificate or will it break?
any issues with Entra regarding this?


Domain controller certificates are used for:

LDAPS (LDAP over SSL)
Smart card logon
Strict KDC validation

If neither are in use, then it is safe to decommission legacy CA using instructions from this article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/technet-wiki/3527.how-to-decommission-a-windows-enterprise-certification-authority-and-how-to-remove-all-related-objects

Or just add a new DC to the forest, and demote the original server, keeping it as a CA solely?

Unfortunately, this isn't going to work. You can't promote/demote DC with CA role installed. You have to uninstall CA first.
